# What happens for the server if the attacker repeatedly makes requests to the server every millisecond for several days?

Tags: php, android

I have an android application where users can enter their username and password to log in the application
I have a server too where a PHP code is responsible to check the usernames and passwords with a database on the server

So, the scenario is as following:
1 - In android app, user enters his/her username and password
2 - In android app, the App connects to the mentioned PHP file of the server
3 - In server side, the user data is checked with the database of the server

If a user is allowed to enter username and password, so an attacker is allowed too
Attacker can automatically change usernames and passwords repeatedly and connects to the PHP code of the server
Even though the usernames and passwords which attacker has entered are not registered in the database and there is no problem in this regard, but the attacker is repeatedly making different requests to the server and the server has to respond that the username and password is not valid

Now the question is as following:

What happens for the server if the attacker repeatedly makes requests to the server every millisecond for several days?
Is it an attack?
How to prevent such an attack if it is an attack?

Comment: It is a `Brute Force Attack`. [You want to look into `ipfilter` or `firewall`.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man4/ipfilter.4freebsd.html)

Comment: Welcome to the internet! Where everyone is allowed to knock on your app's door but your app should be able to properly grant access as needed.

Comment: As long as your login is secure and not locking out your legitimate users then the worst thing that can happen is your server logs could get quite large.

Comment: log failed attempts from the IP. when it hits the limit, move the IP into a block list table. Never let IP's in the block table do anything.

Comment: Put a standard cooldown on login attempts?

Comment: About delboy1978uk's comment, what if the attacker changes IP for each attempt too?

Comment: As I searched, there are some options for the attacker to change IP for each attempt

Answer (score 0):

There are some solutions to prevent attacker from Brute Force Attack or Drip Brute Force Attack that depending on the interested level of security they have their own expenditures but if attacker just tries to make server busy with junk data, there is no way to prevent him/her if he/she changes IP for each attempt too